# stackoverflow while finding tree height

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

I am writing a simple function to find the height of a node which works fine when the tree got somewhat 50 nodes(an AVL tree, balanced), but once the tree grow to a certain size, I got an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`, which traces to line `rSHeight = this.right.height()+1;` &`lSHeight = this.left.height()+1;`, I assume it's because a my shabby implementation on the recursion,

```
public int height() {
    int lSHeight,rSHeight;
    if (this.left != null) {
        lSHeight = this.left.height()+1;
    } else {
        lSHeight = 0;
    }
    if (this.right != null) {
        rSHeight = this.right.height()+1;
    }else {
        rSHeight = 0;
    }
    if (lSHeight ==0 && rSHeight ==0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int ret = Math.max(lSHeight, rSHeight);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I wonder if someone could gimme an idea how to avoid `stackoverflowerror` before tree having more than 1000 nodes? (without assuming a height variable, since this function is for `BaseNode` class from which the actual `AVLnode` derive)
Thank you guys for reading my post, as suggested, here is my implementation, the basic idea is to have a `BaseNode` implemented most essential function of a tree so I can implement other tree types I just learned for practice.
`AVLnode` is the one I current working on, the methods start with `trial` are all tests I wrote to check functionality,

```
public abstract class BaseNode <T extends BaseNode<T>>{
int val;
T parent;
T left;
T right;

public boolean insert(T tender) {
    if ((tender.val < this.val) && (this.left != null)){
        return this.left.insert(tender);
    } else if ((tender.val < this.val)&& (this.left == null)){
        this.left = tender;
        tender.parent = (T) this; 
        // host instance will be the exact type, no real cast involved
        return true;
    } else if((tender.val>this.val)&&(this.right!=null)) {
        return this.right.insert(tender);
    } else if ((tender.val>this.val)&&(this.right == null)) {
        this.right = tender;
        tender.parent = (T) this;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


public BaseNode<?> min(){
    if (this.left != null) {
        return this.left.min();
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}


public BaseNode<?> successor(){
    if (this.right != null) {
        return this.right.min();
    } else {
        boolean spot = true;
        BaseNode tempt = this;
        while(spot) {
            if (tempt.parent == null) {
                return null;
            }
            else if (tempt == tempt.parent.left) {
                spot = false;
                return tempt.parent;
            } else {
                tempt = tempt.parent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public BaseNode<?> search(int key){
    if ((key < this.val) && (this.left != null)){
        return this.left.search(key);
    } else if ((key < this.val)&& (this.left == null)){
        return null;
    } else if((key>this.val)&&(this.right!=null)) {
        return this.right.search(key);
    } else if ((key>this.val)&&(this.right == null)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return this;
    }   
}


//replace the host node with jim in the Tree
//certainly not a good practice to just change the value
public void swapIn(BaseNode jim) {
    //the connections on New Node side are done here
    //the connections on other Nodes side are done in 'adopt'
    jim.parent = this.parent;
    if(this.left != jim) {
        jim.left = this.left;
    }
    if (this.right!=jim) {
        jim.right=this.right;
    }
    this.adopt(jim);
}


public void adopt(BaseNode stepK) {
    if(this.parent!=null) {
        if (this == this.parent.left) {
            this.parent.left = (T) stepK;
        } else {
            this.parent.right = (T) stepK;
        }
    }
    if(this.left != stepK && this.left != null) {
        this.left.parent = (T) stepK;
    }
    if (this.right!= stepK && this.right!=null) {
        this.right.parent = (T) stepK;
    }
}



public boolean delete(int key) {
    BaseNode sp = this.search(key);
    if (sp==null) {
        return false;
    }else {
        if ((sp.left==null)&&(sp.right==null)) {
            sp.swapIn(null);
        } else if((sp.left==null)^(sp.right==null)) {
            if (sp.left==null) {
                sp.swapIn(sp.right);
            } else {
                sp.swapIn(sp.left);
            }
        } else {
            BaseNode hinch =sp.successor();   //it's not possible to have hinch== null here
            if(hinch.right!=null) {
                hinch.swapIn(hinch.right);
            }
            sp.swapIn(hinch);
            //sp.findRoot().delete(hinch.val);
        }
        return true;
    }
}


//A recursive algorithm the returns height
public int height() {
    int lSHeight,rSHeight;
    if (this.left != null) {
        lSHeight = this.left.height()+1;
    } else {
        lSHeight = 0;
    }
    if (this.right != null) {
        rSHeight = this.right.height()+1;
    }else {
        rSHeight = 0;
    }
    if (lSHeight ==0 && rSHeight ==0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int ret = Math.max(lSHeight, rSHeight);
        return ret;
    }
}

//Recursively put tree rooted at hose instance into array 'rack' as a heap
public void stashBST(T rack[],int idx){
//rack was created as subclass array, the host is also a subclass 
object, proper cast
    rack[idx] = (T) this;
    if(this.left!=null) {
        this.left.stashBST(rack, idx*2+1);
    }
    if (this.right != null) {
        this.right.stashBST(rack, idx*2+2);
    }
}

//return val of host as a string object with 'toklen' length
public String printableNode(int tokLen) {
    String signi = Integer.toString(this.val);
    try {
        if (signi.length()<= tokLen) {
            int gap = tokLen - signi.length();
            int front = gap/2;
            int back = gap - front;
            String pre ="";
            String post= "";
            for(int i =0;i< front;i++) {
                pre = pre+ " ";
            }
            for(int i =0;i< back;i++) {
                post = post+ " ";
            }
            String ret = pre+signi+post;
            return ret;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("the number is too big!");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return null;    
    }
}


public BaseNode findRoot() {
    if(this.parent!=null) {
        return this.parent.findRoot();
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}

public boolean fost(T nbie) {
    if (this.parent != null){
        if (this == this.parent.left) {
            this.parent.left = nbie;
            nbie.parent = this.parent;
        } else {
            this.parent.right = nbie;
            nbie.parent = this.parent;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        nbie.parent = null;
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean leftRot() {
    if(this.right == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        this.fost(this.right);
        this.parent = this.right;
        T tempD = this.right.left;
        this.right.left = (T) this;
        this.right = tempD;
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean rightRot() {
    if(this.left == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        this.fost(this.left);
        this.parent = this.left;
        T tempD = this.left.right;
        this.left.right = (T) this;
        this.left = tempD;
        return true;
    }   
}

//print a tree rooted at host 
public void printTree() {
    int height =  this.height();
//Hvae Array of BaseNode doesn't hurt, it's just reference, we can cast 
it back if needed
    BaseNode rack[]=new BaseNode[(int) Math.pow(2, height+1)];
    this.stashBST((T[]) rack, 0);
    int TokCap = (int)Math.pow(2, height);
    int maxWidth = TokCap*5;
    for (int i=0;i<height+1;i++) {
        int numLv =(int) Math.pow(2, i);
        int widthLv = maxWidth/numLv;
        for(int j =(int)Math.pow(2, i)-1; j<(int)Math.pow(2, i+1)-1;j++) {
            if(rack[j]!= null) {
                if (rack[j].val==1){
                    int begal = 15;
                }
                System.out.print(rack[j].printableNode(widthLv));
            } else {
                String temp = "";
                for(int k=0;k<widthLv;k++) {
                    temp = temp+" ";
                }
                System.out.print(temp);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(""); 
    }
}

}
```

This is `Tree` class:

```
public class tree <T extends BaseNode> {
T root;

public tree(T adam) {
    if (adam != null) {
        root = adam;
    } 
}

public void reCal() {
    while(root.parent != null) {
        root = (T) root.parent;
    }
}

public void showTree() {
    root.printTree();
}


public boolean insert(T nbie) {
    if (this.root != null){
        boolean res = this.root.insert(nbie);
        //this.reCal();

        if (root instanceof AVLnode) {
            ((AVLnode) nbie).fixProp();
        }
        this.reCal();
        return res;
    } else {
        //if empty tree, assume the we having a plain
        root = nbie;
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean delete(int key) {
    if (root.val == key) {
        if (root.right != null) {
            T temp = (T) root.successor();
            root.delete(key);
            this.root = temp;
            return true;
        } else {
            root.swapIn(root.left);
            this.root = (T) root.left;
            return true;
        }   
    } else {
        return root.delete(key);
    }
}

public T search(int key) {
    if(root == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (T) root.search(key);
    }
}   

}


import java.util.Arrays;
```

this is `AVLnode` class:

```
public class AVLnode extends BaseNode<AVLnode>{
public int hMark;

public AVLnode(int key) {
    this.val = key;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.parent = null;
    this.hMark = 0;
}


public boolean insert(AVLnode nbie) {
    boolean result = super.insert(nbie);
    if (result == true) {
        if (((this.left == nbie) && (this.right ==null))||((this.right == nbie)&&(this.left==null))) {
            this.hMark = this.hMark + 1;
        } 
    } else {
        return result;
    }
    if (this.left == null) {
        this.hMark = this.right.hMark +1;
    } else if (this.right == null) {
        this.hMark = this.left.hMark + 1;
    } else {
        this.hMark = Math.max(this.left.hMark,this.right.hMark)+1;
    }
    return result;
}

public void fixProp() {
    int lh, rh;
    if(this.left == null) {
        lh = -1;
    } else {
        lh = this.left.hMark;
    }
    if (this.right == null) {
        rh=-1;
    } else {
        rh = this.right.hMark;
    }
    if(Math.abs(lh-rh) >1 ) {
        int llh,lrh,rrh,rlh;

        if (this.left!=null) {
            if (this.left.left == null) {
                llh = -1;
            } else {
                llh = this.left.left.hMark;
            }

            if(this.left.right == null) {
                lrh = -1;
            } else {
                lrh = this.left.right.hMark;
            }
        } else {
            llh = -1;
            lrh = -1;
        }

        if(this.right !=null ) {
            if(this.right.left == null) {
                rlh = -1;
            } else {
                rlh = this.right.left.hMark;
            }

            if(this.right.right == null) {
                rrh = -1;
            } else {
                rrh = this.right.right.hMark;
            }
        } else {
            rlh = -1;
            rrh = -1;
        }

        if((lh>rh) && (llh>lrh)){
            this.rightRot();

            if(this.parent.parent != null) {
                this.parent.parent.fixProp();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else if ((rh>lh)&&(rrh>rlh)) {
            this.leftRot();
            if(this.parent.parent != null) {
                this.parent.parent.fixProp();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else if ((lh>rh)&&(lrh>llh)) {
            this.left.leftRot();
            this.rightRot();
            if(this.parent.parent != null) {
                this.parent.parent.fixProp();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else if((rh>lh)&&(rlh>rrh)) {
            this.right.rightRot();
            this.leftRot();
            if(this.parent.parent != null) {
                this.parent.parent.fixProp();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }       
    } else {
        if(this.parent != null) {
            this.parent.fixProp();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}

public boolean heightFeatureCheck() {
    if (this.hMark == this.height()) {
        boolean lOut = true;
        boolean rOut = true;
        if (this.left!=null) {
            lOut = this.left.heightFeatureCheck();
        }
        if (this.right != null) {
            rOut = this.right.heightFeatureCheck();
        }
        return (lOut && rOut);
    } else {
        return false;
    }   
}



public static void trialInsertionAVL() {
    // for testing convenience, not gonna have a tree
    int statRack [] = new int [] {45,48,35,40,30,8};
    AVLnode adam = new AVLnode(statRack[0]);
    for(int i =1;i<statRack.length;i++) {
        AVLnode bitco = new AVLnode(statRack[i]);
        adam.insert(bitco);
    }
    adam.printTree();
    System.out.println("====================================================");
    //System.out.print(adam.heightFeatureCheck());
    AVLnode chris = (AVLnode) adam.search(8);
    AVLnode futKing = (AVLnode) adam.search(35);
    chris.fixProp();
    futKing.printTree();
}

public static void trialAVLTree() {
    int pool [] = new int [] {15, 42, 12, 29, 29, 44, 38, 29, 29, 33, 0,};
    AVLnode adam = new AVLnode(pool[0]);
    tree oak = new tree(adam);
    for(int i=1;i<pool.length;i++) {
        AVLnode son = new AVLnode(pool[i]);
        oak.insert(son);
        oak.showTree();
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    }
    oak.showTree();
}

public static void trialDynamicAVL() {
    int pool [] = Node.rawGene();
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pool));
    AVLnode adam = new AVLnode(pool[0]);
    tree oak = new tree(adam);
    for(int i=1;i<pool.length;i++) {
        AVLnode son = new AVLnode(pool[i]);
        oak.insert(son);
        oak.showTree();
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++"+Integer.valueOf(i)+"++++++++++++++++++++++");
    }
    oak.showTree();
    System.out.println("this is it!!!!!!");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    trialDynamicAVL();
}

}
```

this is `Node` class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.math.*;

public class Node extends BaseNode<Node>{



public Node(int key) {
    this.val = key;
    this.parent = null;
    this.left = null;
    this.right =null;
}


public static int[] rawGene() {
    int drizzy [] = new int [100];
    Random magic = new Random();
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        drizzy[i] = magic.nextInt(50);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(drizzy));
    return drizzy;
}

public int bfsTrial(int counted) {
    counted++;
    System.out.println(this.val);
    if(this.left != null) {
        counted = this.left.bfsTrial(counted);          
    }
    if (this.right != null) {
        counted = this.right.bfsTrial(counted);
    }
    if ((this.left==null) && (this.right == null)) {
        return counted;
    }
    return counted;
}


public void bstInArray(Node yard [], int r_idx) {
    //the adam is the node we just discover, r_idx is the idx of the adam
    yard[r_idx] = this;
    if (this.left != null){
        this.left.bstInArray( yard, r_idx*2);
    }
    if(this.right != null) {
        this.right.bstInArray(yard, (r_idx*2+1));
    }
    if((this.left == null)&&(this.right==null)) {
        return;
    }

}

public static Node makeTree(int pool []) {
    Node root = new Node(pool[0]);
    for(int i =1;i<pool.length;i++) {
        Node bitco = new Node(pool[i]);
        root.insert(bitco);
    }
    return root;
}

public static Node makeTree() {
    int statRack [] = new int [] {45, 14, 5, 47, 20, 9, 4, 37, 30, 1};
    return makeTree(statRack);
}


//make an shuffled array of integer [1:size]
public static int[ ] shuffleArrGen(int size) {
    int rack [] = new int[size];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        rack[i] = i+1;
    }
    for(int j=size-1;j>0;j--) {
        int idx = r.nextInt(j+1);
        int buff = rack[j];
        rack[j] = rack[idx];
        rack[idx] = buff;
    }
    return rack;
}

}
```

Also, as you might already notice, I spend extended lines of code to check if some thing is null, I wonder if there is a better way to do so? One solution I have read is to have a universal 'nil' node for all node's `null` child.

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Are you sure there isn't a loop in your tree?

Comment: You can [limit the recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022542/3992939) and do it in "pieces". For more help post you tree implementation with some test data.

Comment: The size of tree should be all the recursion depth limitation needed.  The recursion depth can't exceed the tree depth, and a _balanced_ binary tree of 1000 nodes only has about ten levels ...

Comment: @KevinAnderson another limitation that need to be taken into consideration is stack size, to avoid `stackoverflow` error. The simple technique I demonstrate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016822/recursion-java-stack/46022542#46022542) can be used to run recursion at any depth.

Comment: Why you don't go for level order traversal using iterative method ...

Comment: @ZaidKhan for which part? I assume to have a bfs takes some kind of queue to tag the visit while recursion is a more brainless implementation..

Comment: @petergx ...Yes you have to BFS of the the given tree and keep the track of the current leve.. Whenever your currentnode equals to target node return the level of that node...The link given might help you..http://www.plexinfo.com/2017/07/c-program-to-find-level-of-target-node-binary-tree.html

Answer (score 2):

Java stack varies with platform (and VM flags) but it's typically 1MiB. Even assuming 1KiB per frame, that's > 1000 frames, that is unless your VM has unusually small stack set by flags.

As the commenters already pointed out, the maximum number of frames that this code keeps on the stack is `height(tree)`. This means that there's probably something wrong with the tree.

There's a simple test for this hypothesis: add an `int level` argument to the method (obviously passing `level+1` to the nested calls) and print it on each call to see how high it goes. If it goes to ~1000, then check the tree. If it keeps around ~10, then check the stack size.

Unrelated: there's no need for a separate test for `(lSHeight ==0 && rSHeight ==0)` as `Math.max()` does the right thing for this case already.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question since I just debugged it and I feel it will be a waste of time for someone else to look into this.
The bug was that I didn't do the`fost()` method correct, specifically, I forgot to connect `tempD` to it's new parent(while the `parent` did connect to `tempD`), assuming the parent is not `null`

the real lesson I learned here is that **`always fully test out the current component before moving to the next parent`**, if I had done the rotation correct it won't cost this much.

Thank you guys for helping!